# R packages for Bayesian online change point detection of multi-dimensional time series

Tags: r, bayesian, change-point, anomaly-detection

With respect to Bayesian online change point detection, are there any R packages that can handle multi-dimensional time series? Looks like `BCP` package can only handle univariate time series.

Comment: I didn't perform a rigorous search, but from the package description: `[...] allows estimation of change point models with multivariate responses. [...]`